# How to design table for database when we do not know exact data that will come into table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I would like to design a database for my practice but I got stuck with no idea. So I would like to get some tip or advice from any experience developers here.

I want to design a database for a "Tailor shop". Actually, in the shop, our main product is Sewing Shirts and Skirts.
So I create two tables for Skirt and Shirt with few attribute or columns.
But the problem is that if anyone come to sews any other thing, we would sew it too.
So how can I make the table for those thing, if we do not know what will that be and what will its attribute be?

Comment: [According to the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html), MySql supports JSON as datatype. You could have a general product table with all the product properties stored in a JSON column. Another option is using the EAV anti-pattern.

Comment: What @ZoharPeled mentioned. Use `JSON` datatype or `EAV`. Googling those terms will yield appropriate results. Your question can produce a lengthy discussion and will make people give opinionated answers (since everyone believe they can come up with something new or good), some might even suggest NoSQL. However - down to the very core - it's either storing unknown data into `JSON` column or create entity-attribute-value data model which consist of a few tables. If I'm not mistaken, Magento uses it so you can scout its code for useful approach.

Comment: DML reads and writes to tables. DDL changes what tables you have. This is straightorward use of a DBMS. (As in reaanb's answer.) So you do not need structured data types or EAV until you demonstrate that a straightforward design is inadequate. Moreover, you should always have that design, and if you use those other techniques then you encode it into them. Read an introduction to relational databases.

Comment: @ZoharPeled. so does it mean, I can store data without knowing what is the datatype of the data? But how about my table (general table), how many column it should be? And how about data redundancy, data anomaly? This is the most things to deal now. Dont know how to make it better.

Comment: N.B. Sound good if there are many people will come and share their experience, isn't it? Anyway, i think datatype is not a problem. But the most problem is, data anomalies, data redundancy and repeating group... because this is what it will happen when we create a table for storing everything as each entities will come with different attributes. So do you have idea for this? Or it the only choice i could have?

Comment: Well, the first thing you want to know is what attributes you need to keep for each product. for example, the product's colors, the size (might be composite, like for a bra), and other attributes. You might find out you only need a fixed set of attributes for all products.

Comment: Read about the horrors of EAV schema.

Comment: @RickJames yes, i will try it. : )

Answer (score 1):

It's better to keep it simple if you don't yet know what your goal is.  Don't model *things* and don't worry about attributes you don't need yet. Model the facts you want to record. Start by writing some example sentences with placeholders, e.g.

```
On <date> we sewed <number> of <product> for <customer> at a total charge of $<price>
A <customer> has a <first name> and <last name> and a <telephone number>
```

Keep your sentences simple, split them into separate sentences when possible without losing meaning.  Then make a table for each sentence with a column for each placeholder.

Things like `<product>` can be a varchar or enum at first, it's easy enough to refactor later.

Comment: Actually, I just worry about the entities and its attribute. Because if in my program have only two option (Shirt and Skirt), just talking about product table only as other table like custom or employee remain the same and okay, I dont know what can I do when the customers come and sew another thing else that doesn't exist in the option.

Comment: If you have a Product table, it should be easy enough to add a row to it for new products.  You can make the attributes nullable if they don't apply to all products, or you can move them to separate feature tables, e.g. number_of_sleeves (product_id, amount) in which you only need to record a row for a product if it applies.